# I need to receive two packets separately - linux combines them as one and sends to the application

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

My device is connected to a TCP server, which send a heartbeat at regular intervals. At times this heart beat packets arrives along with some other packet and in the program where I am reading on a socket, these two packets get combined and read as a single packet which causes application issues with application logic. It is still possible for me to add some workaround, but is there any way to tell the kernel to send these two packets as separate packets and not as a single?

Logic on the server - accepts incoming connections, when a device connects, creates a separate thread to talk to the device, TCP_NODELAY is set, I am using poll before reading the data from the socket. There are about 100 threads at any given point in time.

Comment: The other packet which arrives along is also a valid packet when some event occurs on the device.

Comment: If you have two separate protocols (heartbeat and data) then they could be on separate sockets.

Comment: It is the server's responsibility to delimit its messages in such a way that clients can know where one message ends and the next begins, and to not overlap them. There are several ways to frame messages in TCP, but we don't know what protocol this server is actually using, so we can't tell you what kind of framing is actually being used. What does the actual protocol look like?

Answer (score 7):

TCP is a streaming protocol. You should *not* rely on packet boundaries to detect message boundaries. Packets can be combined and split apart at any point by either machine's OS, NICs, or intermediate routers. Do not expect that every `write()` system call will have a corresponding `read()`.

Similarly, you must not rely on packets being received whole. You must handle the possibility of partial reads. You can get partial packets from `read()` calls at any time.

It is standard practice to implement message framing at the application level: prefix each message with a header that includes a length and perhaps also message ID. Read the length and then read that many bytes. If you don't get all the requested bytes, loop and try again.

Comment: "*prefix each message with a header that includes a length*" - that is one way. Another way is to separate different messages with a unique delimiter in between them. Another way is to use fixed-length messages. Since we don't know what kind of server is being used, we can't really say which kind of framing is being used.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will have to handle the same in the application.